# How to execute 2 conditional query and retrieve the data in to single table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Actually i try to run 2 query in to different condition and try fetch the both query result in single table by using following code

```
$query01 = "SELECT COUNT(Time) as count
          FROM attendance
          GROUP BY EnrolledID, Date";

$result_set01 = mysqli_query($conn, $query01);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set01)){
    $count = $row["count"];

   if ($count == 1) 
   {
     $query = "SELECT EnrolledID,
          Date,
          COUNT(Time),
          CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 03:00:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 12:15:00' THEN Time
          END AS time_in,
          CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 12:15:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 23:59:59' THEN Time 
          END AS time_out
          from attendance
          GROUP BY EnrolledID,Date
          HAVING COUNT(Time) = 1";

          $result_set = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
    else
    {
      $query = "SELECT EnrolledID, Date,
          COUNT(Time),
          MIN(Time) as time_in,
          NULLIF(MAX(Time), MIN(Time)) as time_out
          FROM attendance
          GROUP BY EnrolledID, Date
          HAVING COUNT(Time) != 1";

          $result_set = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result_set) > 0) 
{ 
      $table ='<table class="table table-dark" id="table">';
      $table .='<tr><th>EnrolledID</th><th>Date</th><th>Time IN</th><th>Time Out</th><th>Total hours</th></tr>';
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)) 
  {

    $EnrolledID = sprintf('%04d',$row["EnrolledID"]);

    $Date = date_format( date_create($row['Date']), 'Y-m-d D' );

    if(isset($row['time_in']) == 'NULL')
    {
          $time_in = date_format( date_create($row['time_in']), 'H:i:s' );
    }
    else{

          $time_in = '';
    }

    if(isset($row['time_out']) == 'NULL')
    {
          $time_out = date_format( date_create($row['time_out']), 'H:i:s' );

    }
    else{
         $time_out = ''; 
    }

    $totaltime = (strtotime($time_out) - strtotime($time_in));

    $hours = sprintf('%02d', intval($totaltime / 3600));

    $seconds_remain = ($totaltime - ($hours * 3600)); 

    $minutes = sprintf('%02d', intval($seconds_remain / 60));   
    $seconds = sprintf('%02d' ,($seconds_remain - ($minutes * 60)));

    $table .='<tr class="info">';
    $table .='<td>' . $EnrolledID . '</td>';
    $table .='<td>' . $Date . '</td>'; 
    $table .='<td>' . $time_in . '</td>';
    $table .='<td>' . $time_out . '</td>';

    if ($time_in == '' || $time_out == ''){
        $table .='<td>' .''. '</td>';
    }
    else{
        $table .='<td>' . $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds. '</td>';
    }

    $table .='</tr>';

  }
}  

$table .='</table>';
```

With this code I was try to retrieve data in single table. Both queries are separately run but I can't run simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check this single query works for you or not? If it give your desired output, you do not need to check row_count using separate query and even a single query will do the same as you are doing with multiple query now.

```
SELECT 
EnrolledID,Date,COUNT(Time),
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(Time) = 1 THEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 03:00:00' 
                && Time <= '1899-12-30 12:15:00' 
                THEN Time END
    ELSE MIN(Time) 
END as time_in,
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(Time) = 1 THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 12:15:00' 
                && Time <= '1899-12-30 23:59:59' 
                THEN Time END
    ELSE NULLIF(MAX(Time), MIN(Time)) 
END as time_out
from attendance
GROUP BY EnrolledID,Date;
```

Comment: You are most welcome @NipunSachinda. You can give me an up vote as well if it really helped :)

Comment: You click on the Up Arrow :)

Comment: i dont have enough reputation for that.

Comment: Ohhh... That's fine @NipunSachinda

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your queries using `UNION`:

```
 $query = "SELECT EnrolledID,
          Date,
          COUNT(Time),
          CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 03:00:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 12:15:00' THEN Time
          END AS time_in,
          CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 12:15:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 23:59:59' THEN Time 
          END AS time_out
          from attendance
          GROUP BY EnrolledID,Date
          HAVING COUNT(Time) = 1

          UNION

          SELECT EnrolledID, Date,
          COUNT(Time),
          MIN(Time) as time_in,
          NULLIF(MAX(Time), MIN(Time)) as time_out
          FROM attendance
          GROUP BY EnrolledID, Date
          HAVING COUNT(Time) != 1";

      $result_set = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: thank you very much .this also solve the part of the my problem